Why might the Bluetooth specification allow multiple values of TxPower in the same advertisment block?
According to this chart which i do believe is part of the official specification , it specifies that many advertisement types can be contained in a single advertisement block.
This includes TxPower.  So it is plausible, if not likely, to receive multiple values for a device's transmission power at a single instance.
Understanding that TxPower not usually a dynamic value what so ever, why would the specification allow multiple values of the TxPower in a single block.
This is especially true on Android where the stack collects a larger frame of initial, as well as additional advertisements before returning a single ScanResponse.
(to clarify, using CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH may well mitigate this when that setting is appropriate for your use, but then additional adverts I believe are just lost)
Really this makes no sense to me, can anyone rationalize it?
Would the proper handling of multiple values be to average them in some way?
This data is often used to determine distance, so I don't get how allowing multiple values at the same time is conducive to the nature of this data.

Seems like a mistake in the spec in my opinion.

@Emil i know, right... PS thanks, ive learned a lot about BT from you on SO

The specification covers this in the description of the field (1.5. TX Power Level):

If the Controller is aware that the power level varies across frequencies, then it should update the value depending on the frequency that the packet is being sent on.

When you say "TxPower not usually a dynamic value what so ever," that's not correct. Bluetooth employs frequency hopping, so the power may change. I doubt many devices actually employ this fact, but it is possible. I would expect the OS-provided RSSI to have been computed on the first packet (remembering there may be extended advertising in modern BLE), but you'd have to check the source code to be certain.

When you say RSSI is computed on first packet, how would this correlate to the multiple TxPower values that would be received with a single RSSI value. To define things, as i understand a "Packet", may contain multiple "Blocks" and each block may contain multiple Adverts which themselves may contain individual TxPower values.
So if attempting for example to estimate distance from these values, the only thing i can rationalize is to average the TxPower values, and use that along with the single RSSI value.
Or am i missing something?

From the spec "If the Controller is aware that the power level varies across frequencies, then it should update the value depending on the frequency that the packet is being sent on."  ive never come across a chipset that allows you to know what freq any particular packet is being sent on while hopping. Is this what you refer to?

I also have never encountered a chipset that does this. I don't know that there is promised to be any specific way that products would implement this, but BLE exists for a lot more things than mobile phones, and you asked why the spec allows implementations to emit more than one TxPower. That doesn't mean it's useful or even applicable in your use case.

Ya, just leaves a bad taste in my mouth when there is no justification or guidance to handle the specification other than 'ain't got to worry about it, no body uses that'.  LoL
